# Переопределение подключения js скриптов в WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Есть необходимость добавить свой код в файл: 
 `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/single-product.min.js`

Я так понимаю, что при обновлении файл спокойно может замениться..

Есть ли возможность сделать так, чтобы этот файл подгружался не с этого пути, а с пути моей темы, например: 
 `/wp-content/themes/MyTheme/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/single-product.min.js`

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, стоит попробовать как-то так:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_manage_woocommerce_styles', 99 );

function child_manage_woocommerce_styles() {
    if ( is_product() ) {
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-single-product' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my-wc-single-product', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/single-product.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    }
}
```